# Append something into interior list within nested list

Tags: python, python-3.6

so I have a nested list like this:

```
nested list=[['Bike No.,Purchase Date,Batt %,Last Maintenance,KM since Last'], ['T101,10/04/2016,55,10/01/2017,25.08'], ['T102,01/07/2016,10,15/05/2017,30.94'], ['T103,15/11/2016,94,13/06/2017,83.16'], ['T104,25/04/2017,58,10/01/2017,25.08'], ['T105,24/05/2017,5,20/06/2017,93.80']]
```

and I want to append another element into this list ['Bike No.,Purchase Date,Batt %,Last Maintenance,KM since Last'] ,how should I do it?
This list is originally created from a csv file and is split by its line followed by its elements

Comment: `nested_list[0].append(...)`

Comment: alright thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

by coldspeed:

```
nested_list[0].append(...)
```